# Dictionary Created from text file - contains() always returns false

Tags: java, list, file, dictionary, contains

I am currently busy on a small university assignment and am having some trouble with the contains() method of the dictionary class which I implemented - the method always returns false. The class looks like this:

```
public class LocalDictionary {
    private ArrayList<String> wordsSet;

    public LocalDictionary() throws IOException {
        String wordListContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("words.txt")));

        wordsSet = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] words = wordListContents.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            wordsSet.add(words[i].toLowerCase());
        }
    }

    public boolean contains(String word) {
        return wordsSet.contains(word.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

The "words.txt" file from which the dictionary gets its words is available at https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt but here is a snippet of how it looks:

```
zinked
zinkenite
zinky
zinkiferous
zinkify
zinkified
zinkifies
zinkifying
zinnia
zinnias
zinnwaldite
zinober
zinsang
zinzar
zinziberaceae
```

I have made sure that the words from "words.txt" are contained in 'wordsSet' but cannot figure out why the contains method returns false for words which appear to be in the ArrayList.

Would appreciate any help immensely.

Comment: Try debug what is exactly in `wordsSet`

Comment: This, `.split("\n");` may be suspect since it appears to ignore the OS-dependent line splitters.  Myself, I would `Files.readAllLines(...)` into my `List<String>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trim each line in the for-loop before adding it. There seems to be some extra space after each word in the line.

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    wordsSet.add(words[i].toLowerCase());
}
```

to

```
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    wordsSet.add(words[i].trim().toLowerCase());
}
```

This can be validated using `wordsSet.get(1).length()`. As per your file the first line is 'aa', but this prints 3 instead of 2 and its because there is an extra space after each word which needs to be trimmed before adding to the list.

There is no issue with your `contains()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try with `BufferedReader`, i tried and worked for me (I removed some lines which is useless). In your usage you are reading allbytes from file, there will be extra bytes.

```
public class LocalDictionary {
    private ArrayList<String> wordsSet = new ArrayList<>();

    public LocalDictionary() throws Exception {

        //dont forget to absolute path to here. click righ click to file and copy path
        File file = new File("C:\\Users\\higuys\\IdeaProjects\\try\\src\\words.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            //trim and tolowercase and add to list.
            wordsSet.add(line.trim().toLowerCase());

    }

    public boolean contains(String word) {
        return wordsSet.contains(word.toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem looks to be mis-handling of the OS-dependent line splitter, here,

```
String[] words = wordListContents.split("\n");
```

leaving extra characters on your dictionary's Strings. Not all OS's use "\n" to split lines, and so you should write code to take this into account.

One option is to let Java tell you what line separator to use, and then use it:

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
String[] words = wordListContents.split(lineSeparator);
```

Simplest in my mind though is to use Files to get all lines, something like:

```
private List<String> wordsSet1;
private ArrayList<String> wordsSet2;

public TestDictionary(String path) throws IOException {
    // my code:
    wordsSet1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));
```

By using Files readAllLines, you let Java select the correct line splitter.

compare your code with mine:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import save.MyColorFoo;

public class TestDictionary {
    // public static final String TXT_PATH = "src/pkg1/words.txt";
    // TODO: change this to your correct path
    public static final String TXT_PATH = "words.txt";
    private List<String> wordsSet1;
    private ArrayList<String> wordsSet2;

    public TestDictionary(String path) throws IOException {
        // my code:
        wordsSet1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path));

        // his code
        String wordListContents = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(path)));

        wordsSet2 = new ArrayList<>();
        String[] words = wordListContents.split("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
            wordsSet2.add(words[i].toLowerCase());
        }

    }

    public boolean myContains(String word) {
        return wordsSet1.contains(word.toLowerCase());
    }

    public boolean hisContains(String word) {
        return wordsSet2.contains(word.toLowerCase());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            TestDictionary testDictionary = new TestDictionary(TXT_PATH);

            String testWord = "zinky";
            System.out.println("My List contains \"zinky\":  " + testDictionary.myContains(testWord));
            System.out.println("His List contains \"zinky\": " + testDictionary.hisContains(testWord));

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---

If you're not sure if the original text file has all lower-case letters and then need to lower them, then you can use Streams to help you do this:

```
wordsSet1 = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(path))
        .stream().map(s -> s.toLowerCase())
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```